# Is it still possible to get an EOS Genesis account? How or where?

Tags: accounts, account-creation

I'm an EOS-newby, who is wondering if it is still possible to create or get hands on an EOS Genesis account. It is needed for an Airgrab I would like to join.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Genensis-accounts were created during the initial launch only and no new genesis-accounts will be created.

The only way to get a genesis-account these days is to buy someone else's genesis-account.